# Clojure - the fastest way to extract the last N bits in an integer?

Tags: java, clojure

I need a function that extracts last N bits in an integer (N < 32 so the result is always positive). I cannot seem to work it out myself.

My first approach was to left shift (32 - n) bits then shift right (32 - n) bits, however Clojure converts the first result to BigInt thus I'm unable to get rid off the first 32-n bits.

Could anybody help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want is something using bitwise and, for instance:

```
(defn low-bits [x n]
    "Get the lowest n bits of x"
    (bit-and x (unchecked-dec (bit-shift-left 1 n))))
```

Taking `n 8`, `(bit-shift-left 1 8)` gives us 256, then `(dec 256)` gives us 255, a number which has the lowest 8 bits set and the higher bits 0. Then the bitwise and will give us a number where the lowest 8 bits are whatever they were in `x`, and the higher bits are all 0 (which is what you want I think?).

Disclaimer: This is probablty the 4th Clojure function I've written, so I'm just learning too...

Comment: Consider this call ``(low-bits Long/MAX_VALUE 63)`` to your function. With ``dec`` you will get an arithmetic exception. If you use ``unchecked-dec`` all will be well....

Comment: Thanks @sw1nn, still plenty of stuff for me to learn I see :P